# Does this type of square matrix have a name?

Tags: matrices

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
        \frac{1}{a_{12}} & 1 & a_{23} & a_{24} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
        \frac{1}{a_{13}} & \frac{1}{a_{23}} & 1 & a_{34} & \cdots & a_{3n} \\
        \frac{1}{a_{14}} & \frac{1}{a_{24}} & \frac{1}{a_{34}} & 1 & \cdots & a_{4n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        \frac{1}{a_{1n}} & \frac{1}{a_{2n}} & \frac{1}{a_{3n}} & \frac{1}{a_{4n}} & \cdots & 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
a_{ij} > 0, \forall i,j
$$

It's like an antisymmetric matrix, but with the multiplicative inverse instead of the additive inverse.